# How to use `@headlessui/react` Transition component in Uncontrolled `@radix-ui` Dialog component

Tags: reactjs, tailwind-css, headless-ui

I'm trying to wrap the radixUI dialog primitive and having a very hard time triggering the Transition element on mount and unmount in an uncontrolled way (ie., that doesn't require an external useState.

I know this controlled version works (simplified for this question)...

```js
import { Transition } from '@headlessui/react';
import * as DialogPrimitive from '@radix-ui/react-dialog';

function Controlled () {
  const [open, setOpen] = React.useState(false);

  return (
    <Dialog.Root open={open} onOpenChange={setOpen}>
      <Dialog.Trigger>Button Trigger</Dialog.Trigger>
      <Dialog.Portal forceMount>
        <Transition.Root show={open}>
          <Transition.Child as={Fragment}>
            <DialogPrimitive.Overlay forceMount />
          </Transition.Child>
          <Transition.Child as={Fragment}>
            <Dialog.Content> Content </Dialog.Content>
          </Transition.Child>
        </Transition.Child>
      </Dialog.Portal>
    </Dialog.Root>
  )
```

But I can't seem to get an uncontrolled version to work.

- In the code below, the transition works on mount because of the `appear={true}` prop in the `Transition.Root` which [activates the transition on mount](https://headlessui.com/react/transition#transition). But when unmounting, the transition doesn't occur. I think because `show` remains true and the Portal simply unmounts without allowing for the `Transition` to happen.

```
// Props removed in `Dialog.Root`
// Removed `forceMount` in Dialog.Portal
// appear={true} added in `Transition.Root`
function Uncontrolled () {
  return (
    <Dialog.Root>
      <Dialog.Trigger>Button Trigger</Dialog.Trigger>
      <Dialog.Portal>
        <Transition.Root show={true} appear={true}>
          <Transition.Child as={Fragment}>
            <DialogPrimitive.Overlay forceMount />
          </Transition.Child>
          <Transition.Child as={Fragment}>
            <Dialog.Content> Content </Dialog.Content>
          </Transition.Child>
        </Transition.Child>
      </Dialog.Portal>
    </Dialog.Root>
  )
```

- Is there a way to structure the code above to allow the `Transition` component to trigger the leave transition when unmounting?
- If not, the `Dialog.Content` component has a `[data-state]` [attribute](https://www.radix-ui.com/docs/primitives/components/dialog#content) of `open` and `closed`. Is there a way to extract that attribute into a javascript variable so I can pass it into the `Transition.Root`, in the `show` prop?
- My last resort is to create my own context provider and wrap the `Dialog.Root` and have the open/setOpen state passed down to the Portal/Content component.

Any help would be appreciated.